# Meteor templates loading twice once with collection undefined once with it defined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

So After hunting around stack overflow for solutions to this problem I came across this https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes and this https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards Both very useful.

My problem is that one of my templates is loading twice, once with the collection undefined and then again with the collection defined. So in the console i see something like:

```
TRADEID
undefined
TRADEID
L…n.Cursor {collection: LocalCollection, sorter: null, matcher: M…o.Matcher, _selectorId: undefined, skip: undefined…}
```

In my attempts to fix this problem I have implemented guarding so my Js file looks like this

```
TRADEINFO = new Mongo.Collection("trade_info");

Template.E4E_tradeTile.onCreated(function(){
  this.subscribe('users');
  this.subscribe('trade_info');
});

Template.E4E_tradeTile.helpers({
  borrow(){
    console.log(this.tradeID);
    var guard = TRADEINFO.findOne();
    var query = TRADEINFO.find();
    console.log(guard && query);
    return guard && query;
  }
});
```

and then in my template I read out this borrows

```
  <h2 class="no-margins">{{borrow.element}}</h2>
            <small>Borrow</small>
```

The template always seems to render blank, (there is no text) so I think that when the template is being renderd the collection is not avaliable, then when the collection becomes avaliable it is not updating.

Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out a combination of the two approches appears to have solved the problem. I added this to the route:

```
Router.route('/problem', {

  waitOn: function () {
  // return one handle, a function, or an array
  return Meteor.subscribe('trade_info', this.params._id);
  },

action: function () {
  if(Meteor.userId()){
    this.render('problem_page');
  }else {
    this.render('login');
    this.layout('blankLayout');
  }
}
```

and used the guard! as seen above